# Is there a way to iterate over values of a column then check if it's present elsewhere?

Tags: shell, csv, awk, sed, sh

I have generated 2 .csv files, one containing the original md5sums of some files in a directory and one containing the md5sums calculated at a specific moment.

```
md5_original.csv
----------

        $1                      $2  $3
7815696ecbf1c96e6894b779456d330e,,s1.txt
912ec803b2ce49e4a541068d495ab570,,s2.txt
040b7cf4a55014e185813e0644502ea9,,s64.txt
8a0b67188083b924d48ea72cb187b168,,b43.txt

etc.
```

```
md5_$current_date.csv
----------

        $1                      $2  $3
7815696ecbf1c96e6894b779456d330e,,s1.txt
4d4046cae9e9bf9218fa653e51cadb08,,s2.txt
3ff22b3585a0d3759f9195b310635c29,,b43.txt

etc.
* some files could be deleted when calculating current md5sums
```

I am looking to iterate over the values of column $3 in `md5_$current_date.csv` and, for each value of that column, to check if it exists in the `md5_original.csv` and if so, finally to compare its value on $1.

Output should be:

```
s2.txt hash changed from 912ec803b2ce49e4a541068d495ab570 to 4d4046cae9e9bf9218fa653e51cadb08.
b43.txt hash changed from 8a0b67188083b924d48ea72cb187b168 to 3ff22b3585a0d3759f9195b310635c29.
```

I have written the script for building this two .csv files, but I am struggling to the awk part where I have to do what I have asked above. I don't know if there is a better way to do this, I am a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `md5_original.csv` content be

```
7815696ecbf1c96e6894b779456d330e {BLANK_COLUMN} s1.txt
912ec803b2ce49e4a541068d495ab570 {BLANK_COLUMN} s2.txt
040b7cf4a55014e185813e0644502ea9 {BLANK_COLUMN} s64.txt
8a0b67188083b924d48ea72cb187b168 {BLANK_COLUMN} b43.txt
```

and `md5_current.csv` content be

```
7815696ecbf1c96e6894b779456d330e {BLANK_COLUMN} s1.txt
4d4046cae9e9bf9218fa653e51cadb08 {BLANK_COLUMN} s2.txt
3ff22b3585a0d3759f9195b310635c29 {BLANK_COLUMN} b43.txt
```

then

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$3]=$1;next}($3 in arr)&&($1 != arr[$3]){print $3 " hash changed from " arr[$3] " to " $1}' md5_original.csv md5_current.csv
```

output

```
s2.txt hash changed from 912ec803b2ce49e4a541068d495ab570 to 4d4046cae9e9bf9218fa653e51cadb08
b43.txt hash changed from 8a0b67188083b924d48ea72cb187b168 to 3ff22b3585a0d3759f9195b310635c29
```

Explanation: FNR is number of row in current file, NR is number of row globally, these are equal only when processing 1st file. When processing 1st file I create array `arr` so keys are filenames and values are corresponding hash values, `next` cause GNU `AWK` to go to next line i.e. no other action is undertaken, so rest is applied only for all but first file. `($3 in arr)` is condition: is current `$3` one of keys of `arr`? If it does hold true I `print` concatenation of current `$3` (that is filename) `hash changed from` string value for key `$3` from array `arr` (that is old hash value) `to` string `$1` (current hash value). If given filename is not present in array `arr` then no action is undertaken.
Edit: added exclusion for hash which not changed as suggested in comment.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*